# GCS Rsync from Python client library?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to rewrite some bash scripts in Python, and specifically am trying to rewrite a line that executes `gsutil -m rsync -r /local/path/to/data gs:/path/to/data`. However, I am not able to find any references to `rsync` functionality in the Python client library documentation [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-blobs.html).

If anyone has solved this, please let me know. If this functionality is not currently implemented in the client library, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

`gsutil` is a command line tool and has application-level logic beyond the client library, so not all of the features of `gsutil` are available in the client library.  `gsutil` does not presently consume the `google-cloud-python` client library, as that library was developed later.

Comment: I apologize if my original question is unclear; while I understand the fundamental differences between the command line utility gsutil and the python client library, I am more pertinently interested in whether or not there is a way to emulate the gsutil parallel rsync using the client library.

Comment: To accomplish this, you would need to port both the multi-thread/multi-process parallelism logic and the core rsync logic from gsutil to your application.  The library can handle individual upload or metadata update operations, but that's all.

Comment: In other words, you'd need to port/write ~2000-7000 lines of code depending on how robust you want your implementation to be.